# How to Revert Sitecore Item Bucket Programatically?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

When I reverted an item bucket manually by logging into sitecore, it is working as expected. But, when it is through below code, an unexpected phrase 'There are hidden items in this containder' is there and when viewed by enabling buckets checkbox, there are no child items present.

Sitecore.Buckets.Managers.BucketManager.Unbucket(item);

[image: Unexpected phrase 'There are hidden items in this container']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following disassembled code what Unbucket button does, there is not only `Unbucket(item)` call:

```
BucketManager.UnBucketItem(contextItem);
foreach (Item current in from item in contextItem.GetChildren(ChildListOptions.SkipSorting)
where item.TemplateID.ToString() == Constants.BucketFolder
select item)
{
  ItemManager.DeleteItem(current);
}
```

It firstly unbucket item and then go through bucket folders that left and remove them.